# Android Upload image (jpg) and some text information with HttpClient and MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, httpclient, multipart

I'd like create a method for uploading image from Android to a REST Server through POST method.
Is the following code I wrote right?
Thank you in advance!

my code:

```
 //Creating multi part http connection in post mode
 HttpPost request = new HttpPost("url-to-my-server");

 //Server header specs
 request.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
 request.setHeader("content-type","multipart/form-data");
 request.setHeader("username",username);
 request.setHeader("usertoken",token);

 //Create entity parts


MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
multipartEntity.addTextBody("param1","par1", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
multipartEntity.addTextBody("param2","par2", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
multipartEntity.addTextBody("param3","par3", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
multipartEntity.addTextBody("param4","par4", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

//Add image
File fileImg = new File(picName);

multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("image",fileImg,ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),picName);

request.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
httpclient.execute(request, retFunc);
```

Comment: Why are you asking? You could test it isn't it?

Comment: Yes I tested my code but something wrong happened because the server response code was 400 (Bad Request). I check the created header and multipart and they seams right...

Comment: Isnt your server returning a page? I see no code where you open the inputstream and read the reply. In this way you know nothing. You deliberately not told us what kind of server you use so you dont want further help?

Comment: I apologize if I didn't show you my code that manages the server response.